# Passing options hash into a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to monkey patch a path helper method like this:

```
def product_path(product, options={})
  url_for(controller: :product, action: :show,
          id: product.id, name: product.name.parameterize,
          options)
end
```

I would like to keep the options hash so when I reference product_path I can have a method call like:

```
product_path(product, anchor: '#product_description')
```

My product_path referenced above does not work because I cannot pass the params hash into the url_for hash. What would be the cleanest correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something like:

```
def product_path(product, options={})
   hash = {
     controller: :product, 
     action: :show,
     id: product.id, 
     name: product.name.parameterize,
   }.merge(options)
   url_for(hash)
end
```

Comment: that works, though I don't think the last comma where name: product.name.parameterize, is necessary